# Command 'find with -exec' within shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find, exec

The command:

```
find . -name "database.*-10-15.sql.gz" -exec tar -rf backup.1015.sql.tar {} \;
```

works perfect from command line.

But if I put it into a script it wont work.

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -name \"database.*-10-15.sql.gz\" -exec tar -rf backup.1015.sql.tar {} \;
```

Comment: Put the same command you use on the command line in the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it needed to escape the quotes?
For me, I get results if I type:

```
find . -name "database.*"
```

Running within a bash script

But I do not get any results when I escape the quotes.

You can also try to debugg your script by either in the script use the setting:

```
set -x
```

or by running

```
bash -x scriptname
```

With escaped quotes, you see that you acually search for the quotes in the name too:

```
$ bash -x scriptname
+ find . -name '"database.*"'
```